# Is the "Google music manager beta" for Linux open source?

Tags: google-musicmanager

Is the Google Music Manager Beta for Linux considered an open source program?

Comment: Probably not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using common sense and 2 minutes of googling, you can infer the following:

1. Google doesn't even let you download the software before you've signed up. You have to go looking for it on filehosting services, or know about the direct link ([here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2793413)). If it were open source, everyone would be free to distribute it, and you would likely see many more mirrors just from googling 'Google Music deb'.
2. So I downloaded the files, both the Linux and Windows version, and tried to crack open whatever files I could, but I couldn't find any license files in plaintext. What I *could* find was a list of third-party software that Google had to declare they used. It's all Apache/MIT/BSD/LGPL-ed; no copylefted stuff. Coincidence? Hm ...
3. Google is already toeing the line with this project, as record labels never like the thought of blanket license agreements. Google knows well what a trouble Youtube is (have you ever tried accessing music videos from, say, Germany?), and there's a reason it's limited to the US for now. It's not because Google managers are nationalists, I can tell you that much. At any rate, this is a case where they might think that security by obscurity is a way to at least keep people from reverse-engineering and causing legal trouble.
4. *(Edit: Afterthought)* The libre-software enthusiast that I am, I have to concede that Google would gain very little by releasing the source in this case. In fact, the service may rely on some storage-and-search systems that they would rather keep to themselves, and that may matter more than the couple community contributions that may or may not come in.

But then I found [this blog post](http://www.joelperryproductions.com/wordpress/2011/06/07/google-music-beta/) by a guy who published the EULA. That should clear things up.

Comment: Very informative, +1

Comment: My primary concern was that if the music manager software breaks my system can I get a fix from askubuntu, getting a fix from Google usually takes months and most of the time never. After reading all this I think I'm safer with the Ubuntu One music service.

Comment: probably yes :)